# how to insert in different table using merge query

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

Here i am trying to add bulk data using Store Procedure
but the problem is i dont want to Update Data i want to Insert Data into temp table when condition Matched

```
 Alter PROCEDURE [dbo].[Update_Customers] 
     @typeMembership aspnet_Membership_type READONLY
    AS
    BEGIN
          SET NOCOUNT ON;

          MERGE INTO aspnet_Membership c1
          USING @typeMembership c2
          ON c1.EmployeeCode=c2.EmployeeCode
          WHEN MATCHED THEN
          UPDATE SET  
          c1.[EmployeeCode] =  c2.[EmployeeCode] ,
          c1.[EmployeeTypeId] = c2.[EmployeeTypeId] ,
          c1.[FirstName] = c2.[FirstName] ,
          c1.[LastName] =  c2.[LastName] ,
          c1.[Gender] =  c2.[Gender] ,
          c1.[Email] =  c2.[Email]  ,
          c1.[MobilePIN] = c2.[MobilePIN] ,
          c1.[Current_Address] =  c2.[Current_Address] ,
          c1.[Permanent_Address] =  c2.[Permanent_Address] ,
          c1.[IsApproved] = c2.[IsApproved]  
          WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
          INSERT VALUES (c2.EmployeeCode, c2.EmployeeTypeId,c2.FirstName,c2.LastName,c2.Gender,c2.Email,c2.MobilePIN,c2.Current_Address, c2.Permanent_Address,c2.IsApproved);
    END
```

Comment: and what is the problem them, just change the `WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE` clause with `WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN UPDATE`

Comment: i want to add in different table not in that

Comment: Then `MERGE` is not a solution. write your own procedure without it.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK You can't do it with merge. You'll have to write different insert statements:

```
BEGIN TRY
BEGIN TRANSACTION

INSERT INTO thirdTable (<ColumnsList>)
SELECT <ValuesList>
FROM @typeMembership c2
WHERE EXISTS
(
    SELECT 1
    FROM aspnet_Membership c1
    WHERE c1.EmployeeCode = c2.EmployeeCode
);

INSERT INTO aspnet_Membership (<ColumnsList>)
SELECT <ValuesList>
FROM @typeMembership c2
WHERE NOT EXISTS
(
    SELECT 1
    FROM aspnet_Membership c1
    WHERE c1.EmployeeCode = c2.EmployeeCode
);

COMMIT TRANSACTION
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
    IF @@Trancount > 0
        ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
END CATCH
```